# Call cs function with data in js using ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I want to access cs function from js function in aspx page after the user click on Delete button. and send id to the cs function.

I try the below codes:

**js**

```
function deleteClick(ID) {
       '<%Session["ID"] = "' + ID + '"; %>';
        var x = '<%= Session["ID"] %>';
        alert(x);
        $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "AddPI.aspx/deleteClick",
                    //data: ' {ID:"' + ID + '"}',
                    data: JSON.stringify({ ID: "' + ID + '" }),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert("Success");
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert("Error");
                    }
                });
            }
```

**cs**

```
public void deleteClick(String ID)
    {
        Session["ID"] = Request.Params["ID"];
        var id = "";
        id = Session["ID"].ToString();

        DialogResult myResult;
        myResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "Delete Confirmation", 
        MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

        if (myResult == DialogResult.OK)
        {
              errorbox.Visible = false;
            //connect to database and delete
        }
   }
```

the problem is the id can't be passed!

**EDIT:**
i solve the problem by change the cs function to static and edit the below field:

```
data: "{ ID: '" + ID + "'}",
```

that's it.

Now the problem is how to change the visibility of aspx div in a static cs function?

```
errorbox.Visible = false;
```

i got: Ann object reference is required for the non-static field....

i try call js on success

```
success: setVisibility,
```

and in the js:

```
$("#errorbox").hide();
```

but it does not works!

Comment: You tried...and what was the result? You forgot to tell us the actual problem. Are you getting an error in your browser console, or your browser network tool, or in the C#? Also, is your ASP.NET application using WebForms, or MVC? Where is the C# method located exactly? The solution may be different in each case.

Comment: P.S. You can check the [jQuery $.ajax() documention](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) easily and see there is no such thing as the "failure" option. Instead it should be "error".

Comment: P.P.S. Using `MessageBox` in a web application does not make any sense at all - that's a Windows Forms item. That's not how you output data in a web application. The box will not be shown to the user. If you're new to ASP.NET I suggest you maybe take some tutorials to understand better how it works and how you interact with the user.

Comment: @ADyson check the post please.

Comment: you cannot change the div like that. You're not in the main context of the page - asp.net is not rendering your whole page, it's responding only to this one specific request. Instead, return some data (e.g. in JSON format) which indicates the status of the request, e.g. if it succeeded or not, and then in the "success" callback, use JavaScript to check the data returned, and then change the necessary HTML in the page. Again if you're not familiar with the basics of AJAX and how it works (which it seems you're not, as this is quite a basic conceptual error) then maybe go and study it.

Comment: @ADyson you are right i am new to ajax and asp.net.

Comment: If 'errorbox' is a server control, you will not be able to access it like this, unless you have set the ClientIDMode="Static" on the server control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Noting your first issue is solved by you which is awesome! :)

and you have another problem in which you need to change the visibility of a div on error occurrence. Well you change the visibility of div `errorbox` to `true` as default value

```
errorbox.Visible = true;
```

and on your script section, hide this div using jquery:

```
$(function(){
   $('[id$=errorbox]').hide(); //this will auto-run after page is completely loaded.
});
```

make little changes to your cs function such as:

```
public string deleteClick(String ID)
    {
        Session["ID"] = Request.Params["ID"];
        var id = "";
        id = Session["ID"].ToString();

        DialogResult myResult;
        myResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "Delete Confirmation", 
        MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

        if (myResult == DialogResult.OK)
        {
              errorbox.Visible = false;
            //connect to database and delete
            return "true"; //if successful
        }
        return "false"; //if not successful
   }
```

and then if any error occurs on your ajax response(success/error) simply just do this in your ajax:

```
success: function (response) {
    if(response.d == "true")
    {
      alert('success');
    }
    else{
     $('[id$=errorbox]').show();
    }

},
error: function (response) {
   $('[id$=errorbox]').show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//Js Code
    function deleteClick(ID) {
        alert(ID);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/deleteClick",
            data: '{ID: "'+ID+'" }',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            },
            failure: function (response,a,a2) {
                alert("Not Done");
            }
        });
    }







//c# Code
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string deleteClick(string ID)
{
    //Your Code
    return null;
}
```

Comment: a good answer would explain both what you changed and, more importantly, why you changed it. Code-only answers just encourage blind copy-pasting with no understanding, which is not a good thing.